# Java AWT Window management, user input, and focus?

Tags: java, window, focus, awt

I'm trying to hunt down the source of a bug that relates to window management, and possibly awt specifically. However, I have little to no familiarity with window management in general, or awt, so I'm even sure what I searching for. I'm hoping for some general guidance on terminology or otherwise that might help guide me in the correct direction.

In the program I am working on, the user can open windows that can be interacted with (i.e. they have text input boxes, drop down menus, etc) and windows that cannot be interacted with (i.e. they just display dialog). When the user opens a "non-interactive" window, the user can still use the underlying program. However, when an "interactive" window is opened, the user is blocked from using the underlying program until the window is closed. Additionally, "interactive" windows seem to stack themselves on top of  "non-interactive" windows. That is to say, if I open a "non-interactive" window and then open an "interactive" window after, the "interactive" window will place itself on top of the "non-interactive" window and won't allow the user to use any of the title bar widgets. In this program, this behavior is not always desirable.

I assumed that this would have something to do with focusing, but I read through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html#RequestingFocus) document without much luck (this could be that I just don't know what I'm looking for). Particularly, I noticed the mention of "VetoableChangeLister" which doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the code I'm working with, as well as the method "requestFocusInWindow", which does appear in the code I'm working with but not in any way that I could see that relates to my above problem description.

Would the above problem be related to window focusing? Or am I barking up the wrong tree here? If nothing else, even some basic terminology so I can at least Google search intelligently.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Maybe: "modal" vs "modeless" (or "non-modal")? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html

Comment: I believe this may be exactly what I am trying to describe, thank you.

Comment: I suspect @JohnnyMopp has identified the problem. If not, post a [mre] and 'let the code do the talking'. Well, most of it anyway.

Comment: He has, I will add an answer.

Comment: *"He has"* Tip: Add @JohnnyMopp (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"I will add an answer."* Nice one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I was asking relates to the "modality" of windows and was answered in the comments. The link provided explaining modality is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html